# Can Bardic Inspiration make a natural attack roll of 1 into a hit?

Tags: dnd-5e, bard, attack-roll

*PHB* pg. 53 states:

> ...the creature can roll the die and add the number rolled to one ability check, attack roll, or saving throw it makes.

Does this feature allow the creature to modify a *"natural"* **1** on an **attack roll** to possibly make the attack a hit?

Comment: related: [Can Cutting Words cancel a critical hit?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/72041)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No**

*PHB* pg. 194 under "**Rolling 1 or 20**" states:

> If the d20 roll for an attack is a 1, the attack misses regardless of any modifiers or the target's AC.

Comment: The point here is that "add the number rolled to one ability check, ..." is a modifier, even if not clearly stated so.